# Chrome clears URL when I'm disconnected

Tags: google-chrome

When google Chrome is loading a page and I'm disconnected from the wifi, the url field is empty and the page is blank, not even showing the "speed dial".

Is this a known bug ? Can I do anything about it ?

Comment: Happens to me too, it's a bug

Comment: Is it in chromium too, should I put it on their bugtracker ?

Comment: I do not know if it's in Chromium :/